# Drawing a flowchart in TikZ, absolute beginner

Tags: graphs, tikz-graphdrawing

I would like to create a graph similar to this one:

[image]

Its original source is [here](http://cs231n.github.io/optimization-2/).

I am new to LaTeX and, unfortunately, I have no experience with this and that is why I am seeking for any kind of help.

Thank you a lot

Comment: The usual way to create these kinds of graphs nowaday it to use the TikZ package. However, if you are new to LaTeX, that may be quite a challenge. Maybe it is just easier for you to use a drawing program, like Inkscape or Adobe Illustrator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `tikz` without adding libraries or styles

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,thick]
% add circulare nodes
\node[draw,circle,minimum size=8mm](first){$+$};
\node[draw,circle,minimum size=8mm](second) at (3,-1){$\star$};

% add arrows 
\draw[->](-3,.8)   coordinate(A)--+(1,0)--(first.177);
\draw[->](-3,-.8)  coordinate(B)--+(1,0)--(first.183);
\draw[->](-3,-2.4) coordinate(C)--+(1,0)--(second.183);
\draw[->](first.east)--+(1,0)--(second.177);
\draw    (second.east)--+(1,0);

\draw[->](first.east)--+(.5,0)coordinate(D);
\draw[->](second.east)--+(.5,0)coordinate(E);

% add labels
\node [anchor=south east]    at(A){x};
\node [anchor=south west]    at(A){-2};
\node [anchor=north west,red]at(A){-4};

\node [anchor=south east]    at(B){y};
\node [anchor=south west]    at(B){5};
\node [anchor=north west,red]at(B){-4};

\node [anchor=south east]    at(C){z};
\node [anchor=south west]    at(C){-4};
\node [anchor=north west,red]at(C){3};

\node [anchor=south east]    at(D){q};
\node [anchor=south west]    at(D){3};
\node [anchor=north west,red]at(D){-4};

\node [anchor=south east]    at(E){f};
\node [anchor=south west]    at(E){-12};
\node [anchor=north west,red]at(E){1};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much! I did not expect for somebody to actually write it down. Very kind of you sir!